# SQL Server Agent failed to start

Tags: sql-server

I have a AWS SQL Server 2008 R2 running and its related service such as SQL Server Browser is also up and running.  Currently SQL Server Agent is disabled (probably for security reason), now, the periodical backup service needs SQL Server Agent up and running, so, I attempted to start the Agent, first of course is to set to Manual, however, it failed to start with err msg to the effect that "some services automatically stop...", which is meaningless.

What do I need to do to get the Agent up and running?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to find out the real reason it failed to start. Check the event log.

Answer (score 1):

The SQL Server agent needs a variety of things to run. Chances are some of them were not set up. Verify the account that is used to run the SQL Server agent and make sure it has the following permissions in local security policy:

1. Bypass traverse checking
2. Log on as a batch job
3. Log on as a service
4. Replace a process level token

You might also need to make it a member of the sysadmin role.